# Getting "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int."

Tags: sql-server, cast

I have a SQL Server table pairing zipcodes and lat/long geometry, such as below

```
ID  ZIP5    geom
1   356HH   0xE610000001044E00....FFFFFFFF0000000003ID
2   35677   0xE6100000010404000000068....000003
```

The problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to convert from one type to the other due to the ZIP5 field having characters.

What I have tried is an approach wherein I pull only records that are fully integer-friendly:

```
SELECT
    zip,
    coordinates
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(int, [ZIP5]) AS zip,
        CONVERT(varchar(max), geom) AS coordinates
    FROM 
        [SpatialData].[dbo].[zip5]
    WHERE
        ISNUMERIC([ZIP5]) = 1
) AS t1
WHERE
    zip >= 85000 AND
    zip < 86000
```

I assumed that since the subquery returned an `INT` type, that there would be absolutely no problem doing normal comparison operators in the outer `WHERE`. I get the following error when executing this query:

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1*
>   *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '356HH' to data type int.*

Omitting the outer `WHERE`, I get a full result set with 100% integers in the ZIP5 column.  Using the outer `WHERE`, it seems to look past the previous `CONVERT` and fail on conversion.

As a few extra notes:

1. The nature of this query is OK with not getting the rows that have letters.
2. It would be perfectly OK as well for the HH (or any other double char pair) to be replaced with numerical zeroes (tried `REPLACE` and `STUFF` to no avail, however)
3. I've tried TRY/CATCH but it does not appear to work when within a `WHERE` statement --  when more broadly catching around the entire query, the try/catch will end up returning an empty set.

What approach would be the best to address without making a temp table--table variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your query this way.  It includes a better test for integers and dumps ISNUMERIC that returns 1 for '-.', for example.

```
SELECT
    zip,
    coordinates
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN ZIP5>'' AND NOT ZIP5 LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN
            CONVERT(int, [ZIP5]) END zip,
        CONVERT(varchar(max), geom) AS coordinates
    FROM 
        [SpatialData].[dbo].[zip5]
    WHERE
        ZIP5>'' AND NOT ZIP5 LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
) AS t1
WHERE
    zip >= 85000 AND
    zip < 86000
```

See this [Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

SQL Server is free to evaluate the WHERE/SELECT clause in the order that it decides is optimized. A view or derived table is not materialized can easily be expanded into, from the outer query.

What SQL Server is compiling is really a query that looks like this

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(int, [ZIP5]) AS zip,
    CONVERT(varchar(max), geom) AS coordinates
FROM 
    [SpatialData].[dbo].[zip5]
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC([ZIP5]) = 1
    AND CONVERT(int, [ZIP5]) >= 85000
    AND CONVERT(int, [ZIP5]) < 86000
```

You can inspect the query plan of your original, but my guess from looking at the structure is that the WHERE clause uses the expression `CONVERT(int, [ZIP5])` twice, so it makes sense to streamline the resolution (calculation to a result) of the expression in the process of retrieving data from the table.  This puts the processing of the SELECT clause before the WHERE, so your `ISNUMERIC() = 1` never got a chance to filter the bad eggs.

It is **`by-design`**.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't strictly an answer to your question but I would take a step back from your question and think about what you are trying to solve.

Why do you want your zip code stored as an integer?  In my experience there is no good reason to store your zip codes as anything but a string.

You say you are ok with ignoring values with letters in them but even strictly numeric zips won't always work.  For example 02345 will become 2345.  On top of that if you ever decide to add in foreign data integers will not work at all and you will have a great deal of work to fix it.  Canadian postal codes for example look like this `K1A 0B1`.  Obviously that will not fit in anything but a string data type.  Not to mention it won't fit in a CHAR(5) which is another common data type mistake for zip codes.

Lastly you gain no benefit to storing them as an integer.  You aren't going to total them, average them or perform a standard deviation, right?  So why bother storing them as a number? An int will take up less space than a char(5) (or better yet varchar(10)) but it's a pretty small savings and doesn't make up for the bad data.